# Banco de dados não aceita aspa simples ' ao enviar

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um pequeno problema onde se no formulário eu digitar somente uma aspa ' ele não adiciona no banco de dados. Alguém poderia me dizer o porque e como eu poderia solucionar isso?

> OBS¹: apenas com uma aspa, se eu fechar ela com outra aspa ou colocar
> outro tipo de simbolo envia.
>
> OBS²: não aparece nenhum tipo de erro, ele realiza o procedimento de
> envio mas não insere no banco de dados.

```
<?php
require_once("../config.php");
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
$data = $_POST['data'];

    /*Inserar na tabela */
    $query_evento = "INSERT INTO evento (nome, tipo, data) VALUES ('".$nome."', '".$tipo."', '".$data."')";
    $inserir_evento = mysql_query($query_evento);


?>
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/57801

Comment: Por a caso o nome possuí aspas simples?

Comment: Tipo assim digamos que em nome eu digito animal's ele não envia pro banco pq tem um ' mas se eu digitar animals ele envia. hmmm então no caso tenho que usar o mysqli ou pdo certo?

Comment: Mas isso é simples de resolver: `$nome = str_replace("'","''",$_POST['nome']);`

Comment: A sim entendi, estarei fazendo o teste e lendo o artigo que você me enviou amigo. Muito obrigado

Comment: @kaiquemix o que você tem que fazer é utilizar `prepared statments` ou utilizar a função `addslashes`.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos estarei anutando sua resposta e irei pesquisar sobre obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar a função `addslashes` para contornar esse problema:

```
<?php
    require_once("../config.php");
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    /*Inserar na tabela */
    $query_evento = "INSERT INTO evento (nome, tipo, data) VALUES ('".addslashes($nome)."', '".$tipo."', '".$data."')";
    $inserir_evento = mysql_query($query_evento);


?>
```